# execvp wont print echo command

Tags: c, exec

I am trying to understand execvp command, when i type /bin/ls it print the right output out but not when i print echo something.

```
char* argumentCommand[11];
char args[10][256]; // inside of this are arguments 
 //args[0] = echo args[1] = "some text"
  //point it to the argument so i can pass it as a vector
  for(int i = 0; i<10;i++)
  {
      argumentCommand[i] = args[i];
  }

  //wont print anything when i type echo something or wont take the second parameter when i use /bin/ls -l
  execvp(argumentCommand[0],argumentCommand);
```

Does anyone know where the mistake it is?

Comment: Do you NULL terminate `argumentCommand`?

Comment: i tried it but it wont do this either like i run thorugh the args and check with strlen when len = 0 i set there a NULL but it wont print either

Comment: @mjcs where inside of for? it gives me seg fault when i do that

Comment: instead of including comments that describe code, please show the *actual* code that you ran. Preferably as a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I wasn't asking the NUL (`\0`) that terminates a C-string but the NULL pointer. The argument array must end with a null pointer. It's not clear what you do or don't in your *actual* code. Please provide an [MCVE].

Comment: After the loop add `argumentCommand[i] = NULL;` to `NULL`-terminate the pointer array.

Comment: @alk But this will only provide sensible results, if the command _really_ gets 10 arguments

Comment: @ctx: That's true. All unused `args` shall contain empty strings though.

Comment: @alk Yes, but for example, `ls` tries to find these files with "empty" filenames then and does not list the directory

Comment: @ctx: I did not meant to say passing empty strings as arguments made sense. ;-) Technically valid it still is.

Comment: @alk Ok, yes, agreed ;)

Comment: ~it does not print the right output: A [mcve] must contain both the expected *and* the actual output in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

To wrap this up:

You need to terminate your argument vector `argumentCommand` with a `NULL` pointer, and you need to do it at the correct position!
So if you have three arguments:

```
char* argumentCommand[11];
char args[10][256]; // inside of this are arguments
strcpy(args[0], "ls");
strcpy(args[1], "-l");
strcpy(args[2], "/");
```

and you fill your argumentCommand-vector like you did:

```
for(int i = 0; i<10;i++)
{
    argumentCommand[i] = args[i];
}
```

you still have to NULL-terminate it after the *third* argument:

```
argumentCommand[3] = NULL;
```

before executing:

```
execvp(argumentCommand[0],argumentCommand);
```

Then it should work as you expect.

Otherwise, the argumentVector is either not NULL-terminated at all, leading to an `-EFAULT` on `execvp()`, or it is incidentally `NULL`-terminated somewhere in memory, which results in the command receiving a number of pseudo-random arguments, leading to unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Thanks but does it have an effect if my args[4] and args[5] are also NULL inside? 
For example the first 3 elments are arguments and the rest are all NULL.

Comment: @Joha: `NULL` is the null-***pointer*** constant. `args[10][256]` is 2D array of **`char`**. No pointers in there.

Comment: @Joha: "*... and the rest are all NULL.* no, the rest of `args` is uninitialised "garbage".

Comment: ahh ups i mean  in argumentCommand @Ctx does it effect the exec if other values in argumentCommand are all NULL too?

Comment: @Joha The processing of arguments stops at the first NULL pointer in your argumentCommabd vector, it is irrelevant what is behind this

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
  execvp(argument[0],argumentCommand);
```

with

```
  execvp(argumentCommand[0],argumentCommand + 1);
```

if `argumentCommand` holds correct executables with valid option & null terminated. For e.g

```
int main(void) {
        char* argumentCommand[] = {"/bin/ls","ls","-l",NULL}; /* Or you can use as you are trying but make sure when you are doing argumentCommand[i] = args[i];, at the end argumentCommand should have valid input */
        execvp(argumentCommand[0],argumentCommand + 1);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, `argumentCommand[0]` is the correct first argument and by convention, `argv[0]` should be the command name, so `argumentCommand` is the correct second argument. In your example, you have different values for the executable command and `argv[0]`, which will probably work, but is non-standard

Comment: yes @Ctx my mistake, I added in the sample code. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: @Ctx Since OP is using `execvp()` so after `argumentCommand[0]` onwards remaining argument has to be executes until  `NULL`, so I kept `argumentCommand+1` as second argument.

Comment: I am just saying that, usually you have `char* argumentCommand[] = {"ls","-l",NULL};` and do `execvp(argumentCommand[0],argumentCommand);`. Your code will probably work, too, but it is not the standard way to go.